# how to show data ( HTML response from API ) in flutter, when data in html

Tags: html, json, flutter, dart, view

I got this **HTML response from API**, now I have to show this in Screen view part.

for this i am using **HTML plugin: flutter_html: 3.0.0-alpha.5**  but my data is not showing on screen.

**HTML Response from API**

```
"message":"<div class='border-bottom pb-1'>New Item Created By Haider<\/div><table class='table mt-1  border mb-0 table-hover  table-border bg-white table-sm table_format'>\n                                    <tbody>\n                                        <tr>\n                                            <td class='font-small-1'>Name<\/td>\n                                            <td class='font-small-1'>Test 4Yyyyy<\/td>\n                                        <\/tr>\n                                        <tr>\n                                            <td class='font-small-1'>Email<\/td>\n                   <td clas
```

**My code:-**

```
 child: Html(
                          data: _List.message?.toString() ??
                              "",
                          style: {
                            "body": Style(
                              color: AppColor.WHITE.withOpacity(0.8),
                            ),
                            'html': Style(textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft),
                            "td": Style(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 20, top: 2, bottom: 2),
                              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          //    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                         //     width: 156,
                            ),
                          },
                        ),
```

But its not Working. i am using flutter 3, please suggest some idea.

Comment: Try with [HTML5 parser](https://pub.dev/packages/html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to  android/app/build.gradle and change the following

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 33
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 33
```

and clean project and run again. I hope it will work

Comment: Still Not Working, i am changing this versions and run flutter clean than flutter pub get and flutter run but this issue is still exits

Comment: what is the error?.